There is no option for internet connection in my latest Ubuntu version after installation nothing related to wifi just vpn and proxy under network
I recently installed the latest Ubuntu version in my laptop and when I booted it, I say that I was disconnected from the internet so I thought it might be due to recent installation but now I see that there is no option for wifi under network only vpn and proxy help me as it seems impossible to check for network on this OS by the way my windows is on the same pc and it is working properly with network and all but not Ubuntu. My card is LAN type and my version is 24.04.

What wifi card do you have in your system?

Edit your question and add all the information we ask for in your question. When you paste the text from the terminal format it as code using the {_} icon above the edit window. Add the version of Ubuntu you are using including if it is a desktop or server installation? Is it installed on a desktop, or laptop, or on the cloud? Does this computer have an Ethernet port? Can you connect this computer to the Internet using an Ethernet cable?

My wifi card is a LAN card

@jyotishkaBhowmick "LAN card"?  A LAN card would only give you ethernet connectivity, not wifi.  Are you sure it's a "LAN card"?  Or is it some other type of thing like a mobile internet (cellular) card?

Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].

"My card is LAN type" is not detailed enough to offer useful advice. Nobody can help you with such a limited description.

I'm new to Ubuntu, but it sounds as if you do not have a driver for your wifi device. If you have the means to use a wired connection connect to the internet using an ethernet cable, try to download the driver. There should be an ap called 'addition drivers' under 'show aps' that allows you to do so.
